# Using first order sentences, how would you write down the axioms of finite field?

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Suppose my language is $\mathcal{L} = \{+,-,\cdot,0,1\}$. My attempt is as follows:

$$  \forall x \forall y \forall z   (x - y = z \leftrightarrow x = y + z)\\
  \forall x         x \cdot 0 = 0\\
  \forall x \forall y \forall z   (x \cdot (y \cdot z) = (x \cdot y) \cdot z)\\
  \forall x         x \cdot 1 = 1 \cdot x = x\\
  \forall x \forall y \forall z   (x \cdot (y + z) = (x \cdot y) + (x \cdot z))\\
  \forall x \forall y \forall z    ((x + y) \cdot z = (x \cdot z) + (y \cdot z))\\
  \forall x \forall y      x \cdot y = y \cdot x\\
  \forall x         (x \ne 0 \rightarrow \exists y ~ x \cdot y = 1)\\
  \forall x \exists p      ~~p \cdot x = 0 $$

My primary problem is with the last axiom, I do not know how to express the fact that $p$ should be a prime.

Comment: Actually, you last axiom do not tell what you want. First-order logic only allows you to quantify over element of you structure, not over outside meta-object (as integers). So you last axiom says : for any element, I can find an other one whose product with the first is zero. Well, it is always the case, even in a ring : for any $x$, take $0$ and it will work. If you add $p\neq 0$, then you ask that any element is a zero-divider, which will be never satisfied.

Comment: you wrote "Suppose my language is $\mathcal{L} = \{+,-,\cdot,0,1\}$." and then "$ \forall x \forall y \forall z   (x - y = z \leftrightarrow x = y + z)$ " are $ \forall , \leftrightarrow $ not part of your language?

Comment: @Willemien Boolean connectors and quantifiers are always part of the language. Maybe the OP should have said that $\mathcal L$ is the signature, but model-theoretists often identify both. If you are that thorough, how come you did not talk about the variables $x,y,z$, or the parenthesis for what is worth ?

Comment: @Pece thanks for clearing up my confusion about the limits of first order logic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We cannot. Suppose that a certain first-order theory $T$ has every finite field as a model. Then $T$ has arbitrarily large (finite) models, and therefore by the Lowenheim-Skolem Theorem it has infinite models of every cardinality.

Alternately, we can use the Compactness Theorem to show $T$ has infinite models. It follows that there is no first-order theory whose models are precisely the finite fields.

**Remark:** It seems to me that in the OP you were trying to formalize the notion of non-zero characteristic. Using a standard compactness argument, one can also show that there is no first-order theory $T$ whose models are precisely the fields of non-zero characteristic.

Comment: hmm, then is it possible to write down the last axiom using 2nd order logic?

Comment: @chibro2 The sentence "Every surjective function from $S$ to itself is injective" can probably be stated in whatever form of second-order logic you have in mind, and it implies that $S$ is finite.

Comment: Sure, second order logic will do it. But second-order logic has serious problems, such as the lack of a useful notion of formal proof.

Comment: As for the first paragraph, I think rather than Lowenheim-Skolem, compactness is important there for existence of *any* infinite models, in the first place. How else do you propose to use Lowenheim-Skolem?

Comment: Compactness is certainly enough. L/S tells us the condition "the models are the finites" is violated in a strong way.